# I can't understand this reduction

Tags: probability

\begin{align} &E[Y-(a+bX)]^2\\=~ &E[(Y-\mu_Y)-b(X-\mu_X)-(a-\mu_Y+b\mu_X)]^2  
\\ =~ &\sigma^2_Y+b^2\sigma^2_X+(a-\mu_Y+b\mu_X)^2-2bCov(X,Y)+ \mbox{ and other terms}
\\
\end{align}

For the expression in the last line ,why other terms equal to zero? Thank you.
ps, discussion above is the leading part from the proof of theorem below:
 "Let X and Y be random variable having nonzero variances.
(a) if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the values of a and b which minimize
$$ S(a,b)=E[Y-(a+bX)]^2$$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they come from product of $(X-\mu_X)$ and $(Y-\mu_Y)$ with the constant term $(a-\mu_Y-b\mu_X).$ The constant can be pulled out of the expectation and $E(X-\mu_X)=E(Y-\mu_Y) = 0$.

Comment: Hugh... Irrelevant comment deleted. Sorry about the noise.